# Is bad Practice? Work with Display Object Container.

Tags: actionscript-3

everyone! I wonder is it bad practice.
In this case I pass the container to TicTacToe class,TicTacToe pass the container to MainMenu class,MainMenu class pass the container to Engine and etc. Engine pass to GameOver class and GameOver pass to TicTacToe the same sprite on play again.And that all display objects are added to this Sprite container.

```
    Main(){
     var container:Sprite = new Sprite();
     var game:TicTacToe(container);
     addChild(game);
    }

    TicTacToe(containerPar:Sprite){
      this.container = containerPar;
      MainMenu(this.container);
    }
```

Is this a good practice? 
The other way that I think is like tell of almost all my classes like Engine and MainMenu to extend sprite and I think is not a good idea.
Is there any other practices to add display objects to DisplayObjectContainer wich is added to stage ? 
I want to know because i think it is very important and there is not much information on the internet.Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Why do you think that it is not a good idea to extend Sprite?

Comment: You should review your display list, what adds to where. You can pass a sprite like you do, although it'll be better if the creator will control what adds where.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax seems a bit messed up, it doesn't show too well what you are trying to achieve.
There are many ways you can reference a Sprite, or anything else, from everywhere.
You can use a singleton class, or a static variable for example.
Lets say you have a general Game class. In the class itself you can have a static variable named "container" that references the sprite you want. You can retrieve it with a getter or with a static method. So that you could, anywhere:

```
import Game;
var container:Sprite = Game.container;
// or
var container:Sprite = Game.getContainer();
```

this makes overall better OOP and cleaner code.
I hope this helps.